# Stuck in a mess

Tags: apt, aptitude, recovery-mode, passwd

I'm stuck in  mess. I recently blanked my administrative password. When I try to do anything that requires a password, I don't have one. Also installing software from the networking bash console(to get something to fix the problem) in Recovery Mode is not a option because **apt** is a mess and I never bothered to install **aptitude**. Changing the password from Ubuntu is not an option because it requires a password, and from recovery mode(using the **passwd** command) is doesn't detect my user account. Is there a ISO you can get for changing the Password? Help!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't detect my user account"? Please include the actual error message in your question.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "administrative password". Is that your normal user account password? If yes, then you could try `password YOURUSERNAME` in the recovery console (replace YOURUSERNAME with actual usernam). If that does not work, please post the error message.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/24006/289138 - is the general answer to this. If you cannot get it to work, then you have a true mess.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting with a knoppix live CD and chrooting into your system. You should be able to change the password from there.